# Mockery "shouldReceive" yet method doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel, mockery

I'm trying to understand Tests and Mockery a bit more with Laravel. I have a repository pattern setup, which my controller users. I want to test my basic `getAllUsers()`method:

```
public function test_get_all_users_method()
{
    $repo = Mockery::mock('Acme\Repositories\User\UserRepository');
    $repo->shouldReceive('all')->once()->andReturn('foo');

    $controller = new Acme\Controllers\Api\UserController($repo);
    $response = $controller->getComponents();

    $this->assertEquals('foo', $response);
}
```

As I understand it, I'm mocking my UserRepository, and I expect my UserRepository to have it's `all()` method hit. This returns some dummy data and I expect to see this in my response output.

So that works fine. The `all()` method exists in my Eloquent implementation of the repository. However, if I remove the `all()` method, the test still passes... Why would it? Surely the test should fail.

If this is normal, I'm struggling to understand why I'd test my controller like this, since I could pass any old method name into it even if it exists or not.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's how mockery operates by default, I like it that way because it allows me to develop by wishful thinking, i.e. I wish my `UserRepository` interface had an `all` method.

You can tell mockery to disallow it though, it's a bit ugly, but you can put this in your test bootstrap file:

```
\Mockery::getConfiguration()->allowMockingNonExistentMethods(false);
```

You could also set this up to control it with an environment variable or something, so you allow mocking non-existent methods during normal use, but prevent it on your continuous integration run etc.

Comment: Right - I'm trying to add tests to an existing code base, so was kind of in the thinking "method X requires method Y to function properly, therefore the mocked class must have that method". So cheers, will implement this!